# Python - Filtering data point with a certain condition

Tags: split, filtering

I am struggling with a simple task that I was already able to do. 
I have two data sets with a lot of rows and, giving some constrains to the data of the first column, I would like to print the results including all the other columns. 
My first attempt was successful and this is the code:

`l1= 11. 
l2= 12.
from astropy import constants as cte
with open('xfluxapec.dat',"r") as datos:
    next(datos)
    print("Element      Lambda      Flux(erg)  T")
    for line in datos:
        ion=line[:9]
        w,fph,maxt=map(float,line[9:].split())
        if l1 <= w <= l2:
            ferg=(fph*(cte.c.cgs)*(cte.h.cgs)/(w*1.e-8)).value
            if ferg > 1.E-18:
                print("%-8s %12.7f  %9.3E  %5.2f") % (ion,w,ferg,maxt)
    datos.close()`

l1 and l2 are my conditions, ion is the first column that contains names of chemical elements (a string) and w is the second column where i want to apply my conditions. The table has in total 4 columns.

Now I want to do the same using a similar file, that differs from the first one not only because I have more column (6 in total) but also because all the columns have numbers. 
I have written the same code, but at the end have the error: "ValueError: too many values to unpack". This is the code:

`with open('./linesbased_fit/tabmeas_a.dat',"r") as dat:
    next(dat)
    for l in dat:
        lamb=l[:9]
        lamb_m,fl_ph,err,snr,hist=map(float,l[9:].split())
        if l1 <= w <= l2:
            f_erg=(fl_ph*(cte.c.cgs)*(cte.h.cgs)/(w*1.e-8)).value
            if f_erg > 1.E-18:
                print("%12.7f %12.7f  %9.3E  %9.3E %5.2f %5.2f") % (lamb,lamb_m,f_erg,err,snr,hist)
    datos.close()`

Can you help me to find the error? Is it probably because .split works only for strigs? Or do I get wrong how split works? I tried other ways but at some point I was confused and since I am not an expert on programming I am asking to you.

Thank you so much.
Cheers,
Martina.

PS: Just to have an idea, the data set are something like this:

"xfluxapec":

`Element      Lambda      Flux(erg)  T
Ne IX       11.0010000  9.435E-15   6.60
Fe XIX      11.0022000  4.133E-16   7.00
Na X        11.0026360  3.804E-15   6.70
Fe XIX      11.0027760  1.142E-16   7.00
Ni XXII     11.0039430  4.861E-18   7.10
Na IX       11.0040000  3.580E-18   6.60
Fe XX       11.0041050  5.477E-17   7.00
Fe XIX      11.0058330  1.537E-17   7.00
Fe XIX      11.0060550  2.335E-17   7.00` #this is the output of the code I wrote

"tabmeas_a":

`#  llab           lmeas   flux (ph)       err     SNR   hist
  8.232600   8.242600   1.0000e-07  3.84e-07   0.73  1 
  8.303800   8.296300   5.0685e-06  3.70e-06   5.25  1 
  8.316100   8.306100   6.8370e-07  3.50e-06   1.92  1 
  8.376100   8.386100   5.4149e-06  5.61e-06   5.42  1 
  8.419200   8.411700   9.6514e-06  7.97e-06   7.25  1 
  8.424600   8.432100   6.2031e-06  3.88e-06   5.81  1 
  9.168700   9.164002   3.6884e-05  3.12e-06  14.95  1 
  9.231200   9.231200   1.1620e-05  3.12e-06   8.46  1 
  9.314340   9.306840   2.0537e-05  2.70e-06  11.28  1 
  9.479700   9.472200   1.3193e-05  2.20e-06   9.15  1 
  9.544300   9.549300   5.9677e-06  1.84e-06   6.22  1 
  9.708000   9.708000   1.5625e-05  1.77e-06  10.16  1 
 10.121000  10.116000   3.7221e-06  1.86e-06   5.03  3`#first lines of the orginal table.

Answer (score 0):

Soo here i try to understand your code:

```
with open('./linesbased_fit/tabmeas_a.dat',"r") as dat:
    next(dat) # -> you ignore the first line
    for l in dat:
        lamb=l[:9] # you get the first 8 chars from l (1)
        lamb_m,fl_ph,err,snr,hist=map(float,l[9:].split()) (2) you split line from the 9th char to the end by space and call float on each substring
        if l1 <= w <= l2:
            f_erg=(fl_ph*(cte.c.cgs)*(cte.h.cgs)/(w*1.e-8)).value
            if f_erg > 1.E-18:
                print("%12.7f %12.7f  %9.3E  %9.3E %5.2f %5.2f") %  (lamb,lamb_m,f_erg,err,snr,hist)
datos.close() (3) i think datos is not used in this piece of code ?
```

(1) it made sense to do that for the first data file because it contained  a string, so directly calling map(float, line.split()) would raise a ValueError, but in this case it is not necessary since the first column can be converted to a float.
(2) what is happening here can be explained by running the first line:

```
 >>> list(map(float, '  8.232600   8.242600   1.0000e-07  3.84e-07   0.73  1 '[9:].split()))
[0.0, 8.2426, 1e-07, 3.84e-07, 0.73, 1.0]
```

see it returned a list of length of 6, while you provide 5 variables for the value unpacking.

now you can directly call map(float, line.split()) on the whole line like this:

```
 lamb,lamb_m,fl_ph,err,snr,hist=map(float,l.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand the error, but I think something is still missing. If I do in this way, 
`from astropy import constants as cte
with open('./linesbased_fit/tabmeas_a.dat',"r") as dat:
    next(dat)
    for l in dat:
        #lamb=l[:9]
        lamb,lamb_m,fl_ph,err,snr,hist=map(float,l.split())
        if l1 <= w <= l2:
            f_erg=(fl_ph*(cte.c.cgs)*(cte.h.cgs)/(w*1.e-8)).value
            if f_erg > 1.E-18:
                print("%12.7f %12.7f  %9.3E  %9.3E %5.2f %5.2f") % (lamb,lamb_m,f_erg,err,snr,hist)
    dat.close()`

I don't have any output because the code is reading the last line of the file and I don't understand why...

Comment: I find the error, it was a typo! Thank you, fins for the help :)